# faster wifi file transfer between android devices?

Tags: java, android, router

I am working with a android application in which I am wanting to share the  file from one device to another through Wi-Fi. I am getting the speed of around 1.5 Mega Byte/s. Is there any way by which I can transfer the file by much higher data rate?
Can you please tell why we are getting this less data rate even the devices and router is capable of handling more than 150Mbps (18.75MBps) data rate...
Is it possible to use [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) and will it be solving the purpose??

here is the code :

```
byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
try {
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = dis.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
        fLength = fLength - bytesRead;
        dos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        Log.i("File Tranfer Thread", String.valueOf(fLength) + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what kind of protocol do you use to transfert files?  Are you using an app, or building an app?

Comment: I am using own written code, that is tcp for transferring file over wifi...
 
                byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
                try {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = dis.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
                        fLength = fLength - bytesRead;
                        dos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                        Log.i("File Tranfer Thread", String.valueOf(fLength)
                                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fast.

There one thing  you can try  that worth the cost is playing with packet size. Try to modify the pack size in order to see the faster solution.  Sometimes bigger packet is faster to send.

1. packet  size bigger  `byte[] buf = new byte[2048*10];`
2. packet size smaller  `byte[] buf = new byte[512];`
3. packet size 3 `byte[] buf = new byte[2048*5];`

Comment: I tried with so many packet size but had not got more than 16Mbps avg data rate

Comment: this is a good speed for android devices, do not think you will achieve better from one device to another